# GNSDK supported platforms

Tags: c++, linux, build, arm, gracenote

I need to build Gracenote SDK (GNSDK) application for Raspberry Pi. I've failed to run on Raspberry Pi B+. But I'm free to buy any version including Raspberry Pi 2.

As you may know, Raspberry Pi B+ has armv6l and support for hf (hard float) ABI. But linking to lib/linux_armhf-32 libs results to "Invalid instruction" when running executable. Does it mean that GNSDK libs are for arm v7 instruction set?

If Raspberry Pi B+ is not supported, is there any chance of support for Raspberry Pi 2 which has arm v7?

Comment: Do you know (either by debugging or disassembly) what the offending instruction is?

Comment: Not yet, I'll give it a try